# renderComponentToString - payload size

Tags: reactjs

Using https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views as a starting point, I can successfully get server-side rendering/client-side mounting working. Problem I have is the size of the page once react has stamped data-reactid's over the state passed to `renderComponentToString`.

The object itself is a JSON payload from a server-side async call and comes in around 80KB. I pass this as is to renderComponentToString and the resultant page is over 20MB!

At this stage I'm thinking I could switch to renderComponentToStaticMarkup and take the hit client side for the first diff when I next update the state but wondering if there is a smarter solution here (props vs state?). Looking at the very clever react-quickstart (https://github.com/andreypopp/react-quickstart) I see the async state is effectively completely decoupled from the normal component lifecycle and therefore doesn't suffer from this issue however there's a lot of moving parts here and I'd rather come up with something more lightweight based on https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views but with the necessary moving parts in place for client-side mounting to work.

Thoughts? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is `document.body.scrollHeight` on that page with 20mb of markup?  A potential solution might be loading less data initially and reorganizing your page into smaller pages, which is probably a better UX also.

Comment: It's only around 20 items, it's just that each item is complex and has a lot of properties. I guess I'm looking for some validation that what I'm seeing is expected and that there's no quick fixes before I look at changing the approach used.

Comment: What is the size of the markup when you call `renderComponentToStaticMarkup`? Meaning, how much weight do the React IDs actually add?

Comment: fixed, see below, thx

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this for now:

The serialised payload for client-side mount was actually being rendered in the react render method, which was a noob error on my part.  This was done rather than stringifying it and passing it down in a piece of non-react markup, which is what I should have done from the start.